# Function for Pre-incrementing a variable return very wrong answer in C

Tags: c

I in my program, I'm attempting to create two different variables that will look the user's input integers and count how many are over 20 and how many are between 10 and 90. Unfortunately, both functions (counter_20 and between_count) return the same result, and when printed, it is an exorbitantly high and incorrect number. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int getNumber(void);
float average_counter(int sum, int numCounter);
int counter_20(int input);
int between_counter(int input);
void print_results(int sum, int average, int numCounter, int sumOfTwenties, int betweenCount);

int main (void){
int a, b, c, e, f;
float d;
bool x = true;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
e = 0;
f = 0;
while(x = true){ 
        if(a != 9999){
                if(a != 0){

                        b += a;
                        c++;
                        d = average_counter(b, c);
                        e = counter_20(a);
                        f = between_counter(a);

                }
                else{
                        printf("No input was provided.");
                }
        }
        else{
                break;  
        }
}
print_results(b, d, c, e, f);
}

int getNumber(void){    
        int input;
        printf("Please input an integer. If you would like to stop inputting integers and see the$
        scanf(" %d", &input);

        return input;
}
float average_counter(int sum, int numCounter){
        float average;
        average = sum/numCounter;
        return average;
}
//One of my functions for counting the number of integers over 20
int counter_20(int input){
        int countTwenties;

        if(input > 20){
                ++countTwenties;
        }

        printf(" %d", countTwenties);
        return countTwenties;
}
//my function for counting the integers between 10 1nd 90
int between_counter(int input){  
        int betweenCount;
        if(input < 90){
              if(input > 10){
                        ++betweenCount;
              }
              else{  
              }
        }
        return betweenCount;
}
void print_results(int sum, int average, int numCounter, int countTwenties, int betweenCount){
        printf("\nThe sum is: %d", sum);
        printf("\nThe average is: %d", average);
        printf("\nThe number of integers is: %d", numCounter);
        printf("\nThe number of integers over 20 is: %d", countTwenties);
        printf("\nThe number of integers between 10 and 90 is: %d", betweenCount);
        return;
}
```

Comment: `while(x = true)` --> `while(x == true)` compiler should have warned you

Comment: What compiler are you using? If GCC, *always* use this command line: `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: Turbo C from 1990 warned against "possibly incorrect assignment". If your compiler is worse than Turbo C, you have a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int counter_20(int input){
        int countTwenties;

        if(input > 20){
                ++countTwenties;
        }

        printf(" %d", countTwenties);
        return countTwenties;
}
```

`countTwenties` is uninitialized and using uninitialized variables lead to undefined behavior. Fix it by initializing the variable like

```
 int countTwenties=0;
```

As pointed out in my comment

```
while(x = true)
```

should be

```
while(x == true)
```

Normally compiler throws a warning when you have something like this in the code